# symfony numberType does not work in [mapped=>false]

Tags: html, forms, symfony

I add in a form a `mapped => 'false'` fields. I assign the `NumberType::class` but when it's rendered it's created with `type="text"` parameter. This is the code in the controller:

```
->add('debe', NumberType::class, 
       array( "attr" => array("pattern" => "[0-9]*", "size" => 10),
       "mapped" => false ) )
```

The HTML code generated is this:

```
<input type="text" id="scg_debe" name="scg[debe]" required="required" pattern="[0-9]*" size="10" />
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

So, I assume you want `type="number"`, which is a type introduced by html5.

So essentially, you have to set the [`html5` option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html#html5) on your form field.

```
->add('debe', NumberType::class, [
    'attr' => [
        'pattern' => '[0-9]*', 
        'size' => 10,
    ],
    'mapped' => false,
    'html5' => true,    // <-- this one
])
```